# Can you do $A\cup B$ for $B \in A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For instance, let $A=\{1, 2, B\}$ and $B=\{3, 4\}$. Is it then true that $A \cup B = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$?

Comment: No. $A \cup B=\{1,2,B,3,4\}=\{1,2, \{3,4\}, 3,4\}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do $A\cup B$ for *any* sets $A$ and $B$. However it is not true that in your case $A\cup B=\{1,2,3,4\}$.

Since we have $A=\{1,2,B\}$ and $B=\{3,4\}$, we have $A=\{1,2,\{3,4\}\}$. This is just inserting the value of $B$ in the description of $A$.

That is, $A$ contains three elements, namely the number $1$, the number $2$ and the set $B=\{3,4\}$

Now $A\cup B$ is the set that contains all elements of $A$ and all elements of $B$. The elements of $B$ are the numbers $3$ and $4$. Note that those numbers are *not* elements of $A$, as only the single set $\{3,4\}$ is an element.

Therefore we have
$$A\cup B = \{1,2,B\}\cup\{3,4\} = \{1,2,B,3,4\} = \{1,2,\{3,4\},3,4\}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $X=\{A,B\}$. Then by definition, $A\cup B=\cup_{x\in X} x$. So we must take the elements of the elements of $X.$ The fact that $B\in A$ is no exception to this general rule. This gives $A\cup B = \{1,2,\{3,4\},3,4\}.$ The above definition shows that if $B\in A,$ then $B\in A\cup B.$

Answer (score 3):

For two sets $A,B$, the union $A\cup B$ is the set which contains all elements of $A$ or $B$. That is, $A\cup B=\{x:x\in A\text{ or }x\in B\}$.

A full list of things in $A$ is "$1,2$, and $B$," and a full list of things in $B$ is "$3$ and $4$." Thus $A\cup B=\{1,2,3,4,B\}$.

Since $B=\{3,4\}$, we can also write $A=\{1,2,\{3,4\}\}$ and $A\cup B=\{1,2,3,4,\{3,4\}\}$.

The most important aspect of these types of problems is to distinguish between (for example)

- $x$ (which in math is just the symbol $x$)
- the set containing $x$ (in math, $\{x\})$
- the set containing the set containing $x$ (in math, $\{\{x\}\}$).
- etc.

These are all distinct objects. In other words, make sure to keep the number of braces straight. There's some orthodontics joke there but I can't find it.

Comment: Not exactly what you want, but how about this? Why did the dental mathematician who tried to index patients to letters of the alphabet lose his job? He could never get past the $t^{th}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $B \in A \cup B$ then $B \in A$ or $B \in B$. Since we can't have $B \in B$. We have $B \in A$.